# Passive rigid body physics not working with screw modifier

Tags: modifiers, objects, physics, rigid-body-simulation, screw-modifier

I'm making a rolling ball animation where the ball will roll around a set of pipes, planes and other objects. I created a spring using the screw modifier and then made a second slightly smaller spring inside it to create a track like effect for my ball to roll on.
When I add the passive object to them, they still will not hold up my ball. The ball falls straight through them.
[image: blender showing the rigid body simulation objects and settings]

Comment: On the rigid body collisions try *Mesh*

Comment: Just went and tried it. Still doesn't work. Thanks for the idea tho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the *Source* and the *Shape* of the rigid body collisions.
In the *physics* tab of the properties panel, change the *Source* from *"Deform"* to *"Final"*.
Only *"Final"* takes the modifiers in to consideration, hence your trouble.

The other setting you need to change is the rigid body collision *Shape*, set it to *"Mesh"*.
[image: rigid body settings]