# Passive rigid body physics not working

Tags: physics, screw-modifier

I have a pipe wherein I have set the physics property as passive. I have a cube inside the pipe. Physics property of cube is also set as active. But when i tun the animation, instead of cube moving inside the tube, it is moving out of the tube. Please advise.

Problem solved :  Issue has been resolved by following the solution specified in [Passive rigid body physics not working with screw modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32578/passive-rigid-body-physics-not-working-with-screw-modifier)

Comment: Please make your title specific to the problem you are having, not just the general issue.

Comment: Also, perhaps some screenshots and/or additional detail.

Comment: [Try the settings outlined here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32578/passive-rigid-body-physics-not-working-with-screw-modifier)