# How to apply collision physics without destruction?

Tags: physics, procedural

The sphere rolls down a plane though I it falls through the tunnel. How can I apply Chris' answer without applying the modifiers?

Tried[0] as well

[image: picture]
[image]

[0] [Passive rigid body physics not working with screw modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32578/passive-rigid-body-physics-not-working-with-screw-modifier)

Answer (score 2):

As well as defining the Shape of the collision you can also define the 'source' :

[image: collision source]

Selecting 'Final' uses the state of the mesh after all modifiers have been applied - without having to actually apply them.

Comment: I've set the tube's collision: type=passive,shape=mesh,source=final..no changes

Answer (score 0):

1. Change rigid body to passive -> mesh
2. apply all modifiers

result:

https://youtu.be/Tg2bOzpCxL0

Comment: Thank you  @Chris it works indeed. Do you know a *nondestructive* way without applying the modifiers?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But maybe some more experienced guys know a way how to do it.